# Standard character set for Outlook 2010 .msg file

Tags: email, unicode, character-encoding, outlook

I need to find out, what type of character set it is, if I save an email from outlook 2010 in non-unicode format. At saving you can choose between .msg file and unicode .msg file.  Is it depending on the version (english, german, etc.)?
How can I find out?

See my screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will use the code page stored in the `PR_INTERNET_CPID` MAPI property. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click the IMessage button. An MSG file can be opened by clicking OpenIMsgOnIStg button.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint for the tool, but it is really strange. If I save both types (.msg unicode and .msg) both have the codepage 65001 (UTF-8). No difference. But if I open the non-unicode message, i.e. greek signs are displayed as "?". I can't find the difference. :-(

Comment: Do you see this behavior in the message body or subject? BTW, why would you ever want to save in the ANSI MSG file format?